# Set Text to a label which is in another Scene(JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx

There is a Scene where there is a label and a button to set on Action.when the button is pressed the next Scene loads and in the next Scene there is a label which is needed to  show the text on the first label.this may be a dplicate Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML but i cant seams to get it if you can take some time off to help out please write how to change the code

First Scene Fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="177.0" prefWidth="325.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.controller">
 <children>
  <Button fx:id="btn1" layoutX="128.0" layoutY="126.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#button23" text="Button" />
  <Label fx:id="lbl1" layoutX="108.0" layoutY="65.0" text="Example" />
 </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Second Scene Fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="158.0" prefWidth="196.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65">
   <children>
  <Label fx:id="lbl2" layoutX="57.0" layoutY="71.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="105.0" text="Label" />
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Button Controller code

```
public class controller {
    @FXML
    private Label lbl1,lbl2;
    @FXML
    private Button btn1;
    static String a = "";

    public void button23(ActionEvent event) throws Exception{

        a=lbl1.getText();
        lbl2.setText(a);
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/2.fxml"));
        //BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

}
```

controller for second class

```
public class SecCon {
    public Label lbl2;`enter code here`
    public void labelDis(ActionEvent event){;

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml)

Comment: Where is the controller for the second fxml file?